# Communicating between directives placed on different unrelated elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to communicate between two AngularJs directives which are placed on different unrelated elements? The link function is not getting executed when the directive which requires the other, is being placed on a different unrelated element.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DuXIRSBP1m4nX9r3Xc9x?p=info

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular
  .module("app", []);

app.directive("monitorwindow", function() {
  console.log("The monitorwindow directive has been called");
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.heightl = 0;
      $scope.widthl = 0;

      this.updateHeight = function(uHeight) {
        console.log("Height is updated: " + uHeight);
        $scope.height = uHeight;
      };

      this.updateWidth = function(uWidth) {
        console.log("Width is udpated: " + uWidth);
        $scope.width = uWidth;
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("The monitorwindow directive has been linked");
    }
  }
});

app.directive("testobject", function() {
  console.log("The test object directive has been called");
  return {
    require: "^monitorwindow",
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, monitorwindow) {
      console.log("The testobject directive is linked");
      element.resizable({
        handle: "e, w, n, s",
        stop: onResizeComplete
      });

      function onResizeComplete() {
        monitorwindow.updateHeight(element.height());
        monitorwindow.updateWidth(element.width());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div monitorwindow>
    <!--      <p>{{heightl}}</p>
      <p>{{widthl}}</p>  -->
  </div>
  <div testobject monitorwindow style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: red"></div>
  <div testobject style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: read the error...it tells you you can't create 2 isolated scope on same element. Use development version of angular for more verbose error and stack trace output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$rootScope` and then you can comunicate between directives by using angular messages. `$rootScope` is like a global scope for all the app, you can use it even in directives and services.

```
app.directive("monitorwindow", ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('message', function(e,params){
      //....   
  });
  ....
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {},
    //....
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("message", data); //or
        $rootScope.$emit("message", data)
    }
  }
}]);
```

Hope this helps, it is just one idea.